# UIWebView pinch zoom to increase font size?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

How to make `UIWebView` increase font size when pinch zoom?

If I set `scalesPageToFit = YES`, pinch zoom will zoom the web page, but the width will be larger than device width. I want the width to be still the device width, but the font should be larger.

Answer (score 2):

There is no pure objective C way that can let you achieve this. However you can use some JS trick to increase the font size only. Try using:

```
//determine current "fontSize" with the help of some pinch gesture recognizer
NSString* contentHeight = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"scaleFont(%d)",fontSize]];
webView.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(webView.scrollView.contentSize.width, [contentHeight floatValue]);
```

And in your html page, create a JS function similar to the following one:

```
function scaleFont(fontSize) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust=fontSize;
    return document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
}
```

You would still need to determine the intended fontSize in your objective-C code through some pinch gesture recognizer or something similar. Please also make sure to disable default zooming functionality of the UIWebView using scalesPageToFit = NO; and removing/disabling any "viewport" meta tag in your html doc.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is a good answer. Adding gesture recognizers to web views, however, is often problematic.